# com.sun.pdfreader in Android application - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf, awt

I want my android app to be able to read pdf files.
I found a library com.sun.pdfreader. I put it in my project but I got an error:
Eclipse can't find 
`java.awt.image`

I looked it up and found out that there is only FOnt class in java.awt.
I updated JDK but still java.awt is empty.
What can I do?

Comment: Android does not carry all the classes in the JSE.  Most JSE based APIs would not work in Android.

Comment: do you know a clean way to open PDF in adnroid?

Comment: No.  I'm not experienced with Android.